# Error with Hibernate XML reading

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate

I have some database, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(450) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
)
```

I have some model too:

```
public class User {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private int enabled;

    public User(){

    }

    public User(String username, String password, String email){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        enabled = 1;
    }

    public int getEnabled(){
        return enabled;
    }
    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }
    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }
    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

I have some hibernate properties, like this

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fullproject?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="userHibernate.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And it mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.springframework.web.basepackage.User" table="users">
        <id name="username">
            <generator class="assigned />
        </id>
        <property name="password"/>
        <property name="email"/>
        <property name="enabled"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I try to run the project I can see this error:

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [hibernateContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [hibernateContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML      

org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:109)

org.dom4j.DocumentException: hibernate.prg Nested exception: hibernate.prg
org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)

org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

And there is my hibernateContext file with bean definitions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-1.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd ">
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateDaoImpl" class="org.springframework.web.basepackage.HibernateDaoImpl">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate"/>
    </bean>
     </beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is a typo, but it's definitely an error in your hibernate mapping xml. You are missing a closing `"` in `generator` tag, change it to this

```
<generator class="assigned" />
```

Comment: I edited but it didn't resolve the problem. Problem remain the same

Answer (score 0):

The configuration files should have the DTD declaration:

for `hbm.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
   ...
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The hibernate configuration file should have below DTD declaration:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    ...
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: these files have the declarations just I don't write them in post. Problem remain the same

Comment: @user3491167, the exception stacktrace in your question is complete or you are hiding something there?

Comment: My database table field "username" reference to another table of this database. Is it important?

Comment: within the exception stacktrace is the all information

Comment: @user3491167, post complete file for `hibernatecontext.xml` to your question, it seems something is wrong with the file itself.